# Using Reply All on an email I sent doesn't send the mail to those in BCC

Tags: microsoft-outlook, bcc, sent-items

A while ago I sent an email to a bunch of people. To prevent them from sparking an email chain of reply all's, and also because of GDPR, I hid most of the recipients in the BCC.

Now I wan't to send a mail to the same people again, all of them still in the BCC. I was used to simply use the reply-all button in Apple Mail, but I recently had to switch to Outlook. When I now hit the reply-all button only the recipients that are in the "To:" field get added to my new mail.

Is there an option I can change to enable Outlook to include the recipients that are in the BCC into my new mail when I use the reply-all?
Or is there a different way to achieve the same?

Comment: If you can see the BCC field in your new message, copy the addresses from there onto the TO line of Outlook

Comment: @John I know that is possible, but that is a work-around. I just wan't it to add all those recipients automatically to a new mail, like i was acustomed to when using Apple Mail.

Answer (score 0):

On my per experience, there's no direct method to meet your requirement, add them manually is the workaround.